# how to prevent some data to appear in the URL

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I'am using play framework 2.6 with scala and I could not find how to prevent some data to appear in the url while navigating between page here is my case:

This is the url shown

> http://localhost:9000/stock/stockDetails?code=49318079281440

I do not this to appear:  `code=49318079281440`

in html side :

```
<a href="@routes.myController.getDetails(card.code)">Details</a>
```

Comment: If you don't want it to appear, don't make it a parameter to the controller method. Ultimately, the browser needs to be able to make a request, so whatever way you choose to send it, it will be available to the browser. If it's a sensitive value, you can store it in a database and send a non-sensitive ID that can be used by the next request to look up the value on the database.

Comment: @Alvaro, if i don't make it a parameter to the controller method, in my case how my back-end will know about the desired code

Comment: My point is that you can't prevent the parameter from appearing in the URL. What you can do, is use a different approach: Store sensitive data in the database and pass along a token that can be used to look up the sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `code` using Session scope of Flash scope
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSessionFlash

However, there are several advantages to keeping `code` in the URL like

- It's stateless. This reduces the risk of bugs
- You can bookmark it or copy and paste the URL and the result will be the same each time you open the page.